# Terminated App not wakeup with iBeacon packet

Tags: ios, ibeacon, wakeup

Can `iOS` receive `iBeacon` packet in sleep state and wake up the app?

I killed an app and restarted, then kept the phone in sleep mode. The device was was in beacon region when device reboot and I kept the device screen off after reboot.
My `iOS` app is not waking, so I suspect its not receiving `iBeacon` packet.

I checked the system log and found that the `didEnterRegion` procedure is not getting called.

Does app wakeup works incase of force terminated app and does `iOS` receive `iBeacon` packet in reboot and immediate sleep state?

If I make screen on then it starts working immediately but if screen is off after reboot its not receiving `iBeacon` packet.

Comment: Hi, you need to provide a bit more background if people are to be able to help you. Please post your current relevant code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, iOS CoreLocation will launch your app on region entry or region exit, and works even after force termination after iOS 7.1.1.  You will only get the appropriate callback if you set up your `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.  If you do not set this up in that method, then CoreLocation will not know to make the callback after app launch.

Testing entry events across an app restart can be a little tricky, so here are a few tips to avoid pitfalls:

1. If is critical that your app think that it is "outside" the region when it was last running.  If it was "inside" the region when it was last running, it won't necessarily get another entry callback because it will think it never left.  When testing, make absolutely sure you get a `didExit` callback or a `didDetermineState` callback that says it is out of region **before** you kill the app or reboot.  Verify this with a `NSLog` statement, a local notification, or some custom UI indicator added to a screen of your app.
2. If you reboot an iOS device, CoreLocation is not fully initialized right away -- I have seen it take 5 minutes after the screen comes on before I get any callbacks.  Be sure you wait long enough.
3. Once CoreLocation is fully initialized, region entry events typically happen within one second of when the beacon comes into range.  However, if the limited bluetooth hardware assist pattern slots are all full on the device (typically this happens if you have a few other beacon apps that have used them all), then entry events fall back to software scans that happen only every 10 minutes or more.  An entry event can take that long in such a situation.  Make sure you wait long enough before assuming it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i have tested more and its working fine in almost all scenarios. just in one specific case i am not able to range beacon which is   Force kill -> reboot device -> immediately put device to sleep. in os logs the  ios is not launching my app at all. also if i just press power button and wake iphone then app is started by ios and everything works fine afterwards. So only in this specific case its not working, is there any condition where ios will not launch location service and app in background if device is put to sleep immediately after restart.