# Terminated App wakeup with iBeacon IOS

Tags: ios, ibeacon, terminate, reboot

This is in response to my prevous query.

[Terminated App not wakeup with iBeacon packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811297/terminated-app-not-wakeup-with-ibeacon-packet)

App wake up working fine in almost all scenarios. just in one specific case I am not able to know whats happening.

### Working Case

When in foreground/bakground/Force Quit ->reboot -> Screen On :Working fine I am getting didDetermineState state and also didRegion beacon Callback.

### Not Working

But only in this case its seems not working [Force kill -> reboot device -> immediately put device to sleep [Screen Off]
.

- Added some NSLog and I could not see any log and also in process list also it does not show process.

If i just press power button and wake iphone then app is started by iBeacon packet and everything works fine afterwards.
So only in this specific case its not working, is there any condition where ios will not launch location service ?

@davidgyoung : I checked your other post and you are the correct person who can answer. When testing, I checked this case also but still not working  **absolutely sure you get a didExit callback or a didDetermineState callback that says it is out of region before you kill the app or reboot** . 
So please guide me more for this.

Comment: This is a VERY specific and somewhat unusual case you describe.  While I have not tried these specific steps myself to witness this behavior, it is conceivable that iOS CoreLocation will not deliver callbacks to apps until the screen has been turned on at least once after boot.  I do not have access to iOS source code to determine why this may be true.  But if you can confirm it across devices, it may very well be that there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: davidgyoung @ I always get answer from you. Thanks for update this one is really helpful "absolutely sure you get a didExit callback or a didDetermineState callback that says it is out of region before you kill the app or reboot ".